# Valid DOM nesting for Provider using React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router, react-redux

This is a trivial question, but I didnt find the exact answer to look at. My navigation bar has following links, which i added using React-Router:

```
 <Nav>
     <NavItem><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink></NavItem>
     <NavItem><Link to="/courses" activeClassName="active">Courses</Link></NavItem>
     <NavItem><Link to="/manageCourses" activeClassName="active">Manage Courses</Link></NavItem>
     <NavItem><Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link></NavItem>
 </Nav>
```

However, I am getting continous warnings like this:

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>. See HeaderMenu > NavItem > SafeAnchor > a > ... > IndexLink > Link > a.
```

I am not understanding exactly where I have done invalid nesting as I assume `Link to` of react router can be nested inside the navItem.

Much Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put anchor inside NavItem.

That's because when NavItem is rendered an anchor is already there.

Try this
`

```
<Nav> 
     <LinkContainer to="/" >
        <NavItem>Home</NavItem>
    </LinkContainer>
</Nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks like both `<NavItem>` and `<Link>` render an `<a>` tag.

You'll need to change one of them. Since I assume `<Link>` is from `react-router`, and guessing `<NavItem>` may be from `react-bootstrap`, I'd say you may need to ditch the `<NavItem>` and implement that part yourself. Looks like currently the two don't play super nicely together.

You could go the other way as well and ditch `<Link>`. Except a few special cases, you don't particularly need to use `<Link>` itself. It does give you the `activeClassName` bit, but that can be implemented separately as well.

Looks like another option is to use `LinkContainer` from `react-router-bootstrap`, which seems to try and bridge the two.

Comment: I realized that the classes arent going well, but wasnt able to figure out how. Thanks for the answer..@samanime